# How to remove certain commits from a pull request using rebase or cherrypick

Tags: github

This may be a duplicate question, but did not find a good answer. If some commits from your previous work gets into a pull request, how would you get rid of the commits from the previous commits 
For example I have 10 commits and I only want the latest commit, how do I delete the other 9 commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new branch from the clean one (the repo's one), and checkout it.

Then use `git cherry-pick commitId` where commitId is the hash of the commit you want to submit.

You can now create a pull request with your new branch

Comment: The feature branch has 10 commits which I only want the latest one. Would I create the new  branch off the feature branch

Comment: That's what cherry pick is for. You will copy only one commit from the feature branch to your new (and clean) branch. The other commits will stay on your feature branch but won't be applied to the new branch.